# Book suggestion for Bat Mitzva gift

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, gifts, bar-bas-bat-mitzvah

I am looking for a suggestion for a good Jewish book (english) for a somewhat observant Bat Mitzva girl. Something which will teach her more about Judaism at her level.

Comment: Let's see if we can narrow it down a bit ... What are her main interests & strengths? What is "her level" in terms of understanding, mitzvah performance and Hebrew understanding. Please edit in as much info as possible. As it is now, I think you'll get too many (irrelevant) answers.

Comment: @DanF just typical american modern orthodox girl.

Comment: There is no such thing. Seeing the differences in my grandchildren alone makes " typical american modern orthodox girl." meaningless much less all the neighbors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If she is a thinker she may enjoy [The Thinking Jewish Teenager's Guide to Life](http://www.menuchapublishers.com/the-thinking-jewish-teenager-s-guide-to-life.html).

Edit: Another idea: If she is already Shomer Negiah or dresses on the Tznius side she my appreciate understanding some background behind them. [Gila Manolson](http://www.gila-manolson.com/books.php) has two books I read The Magic Touch and Outside/Inside.

Comment: Someone I know grew up mostly nonobservant until she read _Outside/Inside_. That book convinced her to go to a Jewish high school; she got her parents to send her. She is now observant (and adult).

Comment: went with rabbi tatz's book. good read for all levels i think

Answer (score 2):

I think one of the series by Rabbi Twersky such as "Living Each Day" ; "Learning Each Day", etc. are wonderful. It follows a calendar and each day it carries a few useful messages on how to behave and think. I got a few of these series a while ago, and I still read from them.